# Diagnosing a Broken summing amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, testing

My spec is a DAC, has to take input and output 0-4 volts, 5 bit input. It seemed logical to use a 741 IC set up as a summing amplifier, with gains of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32. I built it and got to testing, only do find it doesn't work and I'm not sure why:
[diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuP6n.jpg)
Apologies for just sending a link - am on mobile.

I checked all the resistor values and the smallest is 2150 ohms and with calculation they all give the right gains plus or minus a percent, but when I put 5 volts into the row that has a gain of 1/2, it outputs 0.39 volts... this is clearly not correct and would appreciate help understating why

Comment: Those aren't diagrams.

Comment: You might want to read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/

Comment: You need to provide a true schematic. Also, what are your supply voltages? The 741 requires fairly high supply voltages to work properly.

Comment: @Null  I'm running supply off +6 and -2, so when the 741 drops 2 on each it should output + 4 and 0

Comment: @Cursed1701 Minimum recommended supply voltage is +/-10V (i.e. 20V) but you're only giving it 8V.

Comment: @Cursed1701 - Null is correct. A 741 will never work with +6/-2. Try +/- 12. Also, just for what it's worth, your second row of resistors, connected to the summing point with a blue wire, is not connected. The blue is one row too high.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the blue row is connected, there is a 1 length wire that goes up, putting it on the correct row

Answer (score 2):

Pin 4 (Vee) and Pin 3 (Vin+) MUST NEVER BE CONNECTED TOGETHER ON ANY BJT OP AMPS.   ( You need at least 3 diode drops to bias the inputs away from supply rails)

I'm shouting because you **failed to study the datasheet thoroughly** and ask questions about what does \$Vin_{CM}~~\$ mean.  It means Vin(+) must be self-biased to Vcc/2 and used as your virtual and analog ground.

(don't feel too bad, it happens too often here)